# Get Checkbox Randomly

Tags: c#, random

I have 10 checkboxes in my application .The checkbox names are

```
checkbox0,
checkbox1,
checkbox2, 
.
.
checkbox9
```

i want to select randomly which checkbox . Ie if i select checkbox0 for first time ,next time it should select say checkbox7 .

Answer (score 3):

Put them in a list (`List<CheckBox>`), create a new `Random` and select by index:

```
var random = new Random();
var checkbox = list[random.Next(0, list.Length)];
```

(To prevent repeated selections you could remove the chosen control from the list afterwards (`list.Remove(checkbox)`))

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Random rand = new System.Random();
int x = rand.Next(0,10); //limiting the number from 0 to 9
if(x == 0)
checkbox0.checked = true;
else if (x == 1)
checkbox1.checked = true;
... and so on
```

This is my first time on stack overflow so if its not what you were looking for I'm sorry.

Comment: nice try, but i think H.B. solution is more elegant and is easier to maintain if checkboxes are added or removed from the form.

Comment: I really wish my classes would go more in depth about things like lists, i have very little knowledge about them, they seem very useful